# AH00526 Error while running python using Apache on Ubuntu

Tags: python, apache, web-services

I was trying to run python, using Xampp-8.1.12 with Apache 2.4, since my project use python script. So I added the following lines to `/opt/lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` :

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

following the web tutorials. But as I added the above and restarted Apache server it is not starting with following error:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 12 of /opt/lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'ScriptInterpreterSource', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I have python3 and python 2 both installed and I have mentioned in the file, I would like to run, that the file is to be run with python3.

[image: Image description of the error]

Comment: You have to remove the `ScriptInterpreterSource` from your `httpd.conf` file, because it is not recognized by Apache and you get that error. Try using `AddHandler` so Apache runs the Python interpreter on your `.py` files.

Comment: Thank you @Gandhi now it is running. Consider adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `ScriptInterpreterSource` from your `httpd.conf` file, because it is not recognized by Apache and you get that error. Try using `AddHandler` so Apache runs the Python interpreter on your `.py` files.